# CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException when attempting to set a return on .Equals

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

I'm using the latest version of NSubstitute, and I get the following error:

```
NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233088   
Message=Could not find a call to return from.

Make sure you called Returns() after calling your substitute (for example: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(value)), and that you are not configuring other substitutes within Returns() (for example, avoid this: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub())).

If you substituted for a class rather than an interface, check that the call to your substitute was on a virtual/abstract member. Return values cannot be configured for non-virtual/non-abstract members.

Correct use:    mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);

Potentially problematic use:

mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub()); 

Instead try:    

var returnValue = ConfigOtherSub();     

mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);
```

Here's a minimum project that replicates the error:

```
using System;
using NSubstitute;

public interface A
{
    string GetText();
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var aMock = Substitute.For<A, IEquatable<string>>();

        aMock.Equals("foo").Returns(true);
    }
}
```

I suspect it's because NSubstitute cannot mock methods for which there's already an implementation, and even though these are interfaces being mocked, it's possible that the default implementation of `.Equals` from `object` is causing difficulties.

Is there some other way to set a return value for `.Equals` in NSubstitute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it is the `Object.Equals` that is causing the problem. There is [more info in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970297/906).

To work around you can force it to use `IEquatable<T>.Equals` like this:

```
var aMock = Substitute.For<A, IEquatable<string>>();
var a = (IEquatable<string>)aMock;
a.Equals("foo").Returns(true);
```

That requires the code being tested to also use that method rather than the one on `Object`.

This kind of difficulty has led me to try to avoid mocking `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, and `ToString` with NSubstitute. One ugly but effective way is to use your own equals implementation `IsEqualTo(A a)` that delegates to the underlying `Object.Equals` in the real code, but provides an easy place to mock out.

Comment: I think the latter would probably mess up the public API a bit, developer expectations-wise, so for me it's either the former, which is probably acceptable, or I build a custom mock for the class in question.